# Finding the region of attraction using a Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions, basins-of-attraction

I'm trying to find an estimate for the region of attraction of an equilibrium point. The notes from Nonlinear Control by Khalil suggest that defining
$$
V(x) = x^TPx,
$$
where $P$ is the solution of
$$
PA+A^TP=-I,
$$
will yield the best results for an estimate. It also assures that the estimate can be found from these types of Lyapunov functions for exponentially stable equilibrium points.

The system I am studying is defined by
$$
\begin{gathered}
\dot{x}_1 = x_1 - x_1^3 + x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 = x_1 - 3x_2. 
\end{gathered}
$$
The linealization matrix around the equilibrium point $x^* = \{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\}$, is
$A = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
-3 & 1 \\
 1 & -3\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$,
and so,
$P = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
3/16 & 1/16 \\
 1/16 & 3/16\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$.

Given the previous values, I took the derivative of V(x) w.r.t. time and substituted the system in the equation (did it in Mathematica to try and simplify it as much as possible), giving
$$
\dot{V}(x) = \frac{1}{8}\left(4x_1^2-3x_1^4+4x_1x_2-x_1^3x_2-8x_2^2\right).
$$
Now I need to find a region where $\dot{V}(x)$ is negative definite, but when I try to use inequalities with the norm of $x$ I get only positive norms raised to a power, and so $\dot{V}(x)$ can never be negative definite.

Using
$$
|x_1|\leq||x||, \quad |x_1x_2|\leq\frac{1}{2}||x||^2,
$$
I arrived at
$$
\begin{gathered}
\dot{V}(x) \leq \frac{1}{8}\left(4||x||^2+3||x||^4+2||x||^2+\frac{1}{2}||x||^4+8||x||^2\right) \\
\leq \frac{1}{8}\left(14||x||^2+\frac{7}{2}||x||^4\right).
\end{gathered}
$$
As you can see, it never is negative.

Am I being overly aggresive with converting everything to norms? How can I find the region where $\dot{V}(x)$ is negative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. The overall strategy and the choice of $P$  are good, but you should then use the Lyapunov function $y^TPy$, where $y = x - x^\ast$, since the equilibrium under study is not the origin.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks a lot!, I see, then I'd have a $\dot{V}(y)$ with $y + x*$ instead of $x$ in the function? With a different system that had an equilibrium outside the origin I skipped the change of variable and still could find the basin, so I thought it'd work for every equilibrium.

Comment: You can either write down the system for $ y(t) = x(t) - x^\ast$ and work with $V_0= y^TPy$, or work with $V_1(x) = (x-x^\ast)^TP(x-x^\ast)$ and use the original system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correcting an error done.

In my previous answer (this is the edition of changes) I considered

$$
\dot V = (x,y)P(x-x^3+y,x-3y) \ \ \text{translated to}\ \  (x^*, y^*)\ \ \text{which is wrong}
$$

The correct procedure is to consider

$$
\dot V = (x-x^*,y-y^*)P(x-x^3+y,x-3y)
$$

thus giving

$$
\dot V = -\frac{3 x^4}{8}-\frac{x^3 y}{8}+\frac{5 x^3}{6 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x y}{2}-\frac{4 x}{3 \sqrt{3}}-y^2+\frac{2 y}{3 \sqrt{3}}
$$

thus we have in light blue the region with $\dot V\le 0$ and in black the contour lines for $V$. As we can observe, for the choose Lyapounov function, the small attraction basin is shown by the tangent inner level curve.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! So, the region where $\dot{V}(x) \leq 0$ is enclosed by those curves?

Comment: $\dot V(x) \le 0$ is OUT those curves.

Comment: Then would that mean that this equilibrium isn't even locally asymptotically stable? Linearization suggests that it is exponentially stable near this equilibrium, but if one were to take a ball around that point, then it would always have some places where $\dot{V}(x) > 0$.

Comment: Corrected a mistake in the processing for $\dot V$

Comment: I see, I was disregarding the translation and it threw off all of my graphs and analysis. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I get the following image for region of attraction:

[image]

Yellow: $\dot{V}(x) > 0$

Teal: $\dot{V}(x) \leq 0$

Blue: $\dot{V}(x) \leq 0$ and $V(x) \leq 0.244$

Black cross: $x^* = (\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}})$

The Lyapunov function is $V(x) = (x - x^*)^T\begin{pmatrix} \frac{3}{16}&\frac{1}{16}\\ \frac{1}{16} & \frac{3}{16} \end{pmatrix}(x - x^*)$ for the system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_1 - x_1^3 + x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= x_1 - 3 x_2
\end{align}
$$

The equilibrium is stable because the linearized system at $x^*$ has eigenvalues $-2$ and $-4$.

So $V(x) \leq 0.244$ is sufficient that $x \rightarrow x^*$.

Comment: Thanks!, I didn't take into account the translation... How did you get the value of the upper bound for V(x)?

Comment: @Octavio Just check the point where blue hits yellow.